# python en cpanel?

Tags: python, django, cpanel

[!Hola, Soy nuevo en esto. Mi problema es quedesarrolle una appWeb en Django y al momento de subirla mi jefe me dice que la suba en este Cpanel (nunca eh subido una pagina web a Internet xd), investigando en internet vi que para subirlo necesito ese software "Setup Python App" en mi Cpanel (primera imagen ) 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Pero en el Cpanel que tengo solo tiene estas aplicaciones.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es posible instalar esa app que me falta?. Creo que tengo acceso a SSH pero no tengo idea de como instalar esa app. O  de plano tengo que realizar todo denuevo y hacerla en PHP :C

Comment: Parece que cpanel sólo soporta scripts sencillos python ejecutados vía cgi (por lo que he podido leer [aqui](https://www.crybit.com/python-scripts-with-cpanel/) o [aqui](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/short-guide-to-running-python-scripts-with-cpanel.244361/)). No creo que sea tu caso, ya que a juzgar por las etiquetas de la pregunta se trata de una aplicación django.

Comment: No tengo claro si hay o no soporte para django, aunque sea una [característica solicitada](https://features.cpanel.net/topic/django-support). Quizás podría hacerse pero [parece complicado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625151/how-to-install-django-on-cpanel#15625888), y al final aconsejan cambiar de proveedor y la respuesta tiene ya 5 años...

Comment: yo estoy trabajando también en una web en Django y te comento que la solución que nosotros le dimos fue subira a pythonanywhere, te dejo el enlace [aquí](https://www.pythonanywhere.com). Hay muy pocos hostings que soporten python o django y los que lo hacen son bastante caros, como azure o amazon web service.

Comment: Bueno, gracias. Creo que tendre que volver a desarrollar la pagina con PHP T_T

Comment: En mi Cpanel he visto ese Setup Python App, consulta con tu adminitrador de hosting si te lo puede agregar.

Comment: tuve el mismo problema @CristhianFernandezZagastizab te sugiero consultar con el servidor hosting a ver si te pueden implementar python y soportan Django, caso contrario deberas ver un proveedor VPN , tambien hay pythonanywhere, amazon ws, entre otros..

Comment: tuve el mismo problema. Esto lo respondi aqui https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/262600/c%c3%b3mo-desplegar-correctamente-una-aplicacion-django-en-un-cpanel/350418#350418